# Is there any way to create multiple new columns for a table based on result set with mysql script

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I want to create a new column for each language type in a language table.

so each language can be found with:   select code from languages;

For each language code I want a new column in another table..

Manually I would run

alter table blah add column text_en_GB;
alter table blah add column text_fr_FR; 
...

I hoped I could build queries using:
select concat ("alter table blah add column text_", code, ";\n") from languages;
then prepare and execute this but that doesn't work with a block of statements. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way :-)

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE blah ', GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('ADD COLUMN `blah_name_', `language_code`, '` varchar(255) NOT NULL') SEPARATOR ", "), ";" ) FROM `language` INTO @poo;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @poo;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [CURSORS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) .

You can define a procedure that opens a cursor for a `SELECT` statement (the one that extract all the languages that you need) and the inside the `LOOP` of the cursor you do an `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` with the desired strings that you are extracting ;)

You can find some examples [here](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Working_With_Cursors.htm)

Comment: I considered this solution but looks like rather a lot of code for what it does! Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a better way. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: It's not that bad ... in a 20-30 lines of code you easy achieve what you're seeking :) don't forget to select the best answer!